# Is the load event fired only once on a window? (IE 10)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, dom

Is the load event fired only after a window has been created and a document loaded and never again? Look at this

```
function func1()
{
    var somebutton = win.document.getElementById('somebutton');
    somebutton.click();
    win.detachEvent('onload', func1);
    win.attachEvent('onload', func2);
}

win = window.open('http://www.somesite.com');
win.attachEvent('onload', func1);
```

I get to func1, but not to func2. Why not? A new document is loaded into win but the load event seems not to be fired. How shall I get to func2? I'm working with IE 10.

Comment: Event listeners(and javascript in general) is not preserved by navigation. The browser creates an entirely new context. Only the scripts from `somesite.com` will load in that context, you can't have visibility on that from your page.

Comment: @KarlReid What do you mean, entirely new context? I still have win. The script above will be working on the new document through win. This works, I just don't know how to wait for the new document to load, except by setting timeout.